# DIfferent between break and return in swith loop JS ? And what using in my logic ( looking code )

Tags: javascript

And i don't know is this good solution to using return or to use break?

```
switch (arg.seriesName) {
    case 'Test':
        return  'Test'

    case 'One':
        return 'One'

    case 'two':
        return  'two'

    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: What is a switch loop?

Comment: switch ........ instead if...

Comment: that is a switch statement. There is no switch loop

Answer (score 0):

`break` will allow you the function to continue processing, whereas `return` will end the function. Returning out of the switch is fine if that's all you want to do in the function.

E.g.

**Return**

```
function foo(x) {
   switch(x) {
      case 'y':
          return;
   }
   // This will never run if x === 'y'
}
```

**Break**

```
function foo(x) {
   switch(x) {
      case 'y':
          break;
   }
   // This will still run if x === 'y'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> A case clause used to match against expression. If the expression matches the specified valueN, the statements inside the case clause are executed until either the end of the switch statement or a break.

The break stops to execution the other cases.
In your example you return inside the case so it will left the function and return the value so there is no need for the **break;**

Here with the breaks in each case prints only the case which is hitting

```js
const expr = 'Papayas';
switch (expr) {
  case 'Oranges':
    console.log('Oranges are $0.59 a pound.');
    break;
  case 'Mangoes':
  case 'Papayas':
    console.log('Mangoes and papayas are $2.79 a pound.');
    // expected output: "Mangoes and papayas are $2.79 a pound."
    break;
  default:
    console.log(`Sorry, we are out of ${expr}.`);
}
```

But if you forget the break it also prints out the cases after the hitting one

```js
const expr = 'Papayas';
switch (expr) {
  case 'Oranges':
    console.log('Oranges are $0.59 a pound.');
  case 'Mangoes':
  case 'Papayas':
    console.log('Mangoes and papayas are $2.79 a pound.');
    // expected output: "Mangoes and papayas are $2.79 a pound."
  default:
    console.log(`Sorry, we are out of ${expr}.`);
}
```

Comment: In this situation if one match it is enough.. Because maybe is return better solution.

Comment: with return it will immediately give back the result

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, that one is a switch **statement**, not a loop.
Anyway, break is used to stop fall-through: that is, when one of the cases match, it prevents the other from matching as well.

The difference between `return` and `break` depends on your context: if you're inside a function, `return` will stop the execution of the function altogether, whereas `break` will make the switch statement only match one case and then go on with the execution.